# Why does parseInt(NaN, 32) return a number?

Tags: javascript, integer

```
parseInt(NaN, 32) === 23895
```

Why does that return a number?
(Also works with `null` or `undefined`)

Comment: This is probably due to `"NaN"` being a valid base 32 number? It works with any radix higher than 23 `parseInt('NaN', 24)`

Comment: The first argument to `parseInt()` is always coerced to a string *before* any parsing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`23895`, in base 32, is `nan`.

`n = 23` and `a = 10`. So `nan = 23 + 10*32 + 23*32^2 = 23895`.

I guess JavaScript is being *"helpful"* and coercing `NaN` into a string, before trying to parse it into a number.

I hate JavaScript.

Comment: It's not being "helpful", it's in the definition of the function in the language spec. It's called **parse**Int. The word "parse" indicates that a textual source is being interpreted according to a syntax. It makes no sense to "parse" a number.

Comment: It also makes no sense to "parse" `NaN`!! Parsing implies a string. In my opinion, any sane language should raise an exception here (or fail to compile). JavaScript is trying to "helpfully" accept nonsense input, and provides a nonsense answer.

Comment: Well that's a valid opinion, but traditionally JavaScript has *not* been strict in that sense because its origins were in a time when non-professional programmers were expected to be a large part of the user base. Indeed that remains true today, as can be seen by skimming the JavaScript questions here. It's like how browsers deal with absurdly wrong HTML markup without just tossing it all out as an error.